# Struts Method with Parameter from Ajax GET

Tags: struts2, struts

I issue a GET Ajax request from JavaScript,

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: "myMethod?id=" + id, 
        success: function(data) {
           // ...
        } 

    });
```

The server app is Struts with struts.xml. The action is mapped in struts.xml as

```
<action name="myMethod" method="myMethod" class="myapp.SomeClass">
        <result type="json">
            <param name="contentType">text/plain</param>
        </result>       
    </action>
```

and the class has the method which takes a parameter,

```
public String myMethod(int id) {
  //..      
}
```

But the error I'm getting is

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: myapp.myMethod()
```

From this thread I know Struts doesn't support parameterized mapped methods,
[Calling method with arguments in struts 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193803/calling-method-with-arguments-in-struts-2)

But their solution (to introduce an Action property) doesn't seem appropriate here. `id` is **not** a server-maintained form field or action property, it's something passed in from the JS layer.

So how do I handle this custom JS Ajax scenario with a GET parameter in Struts?

I'm not using annotations, even though this is a Struts2 app. The app as a whole is written with configurations, not annotations.

Answer (score 1):

For data binding in struts you gotta set `int id` as a field of your action class with its setter and getter and the method should work with this class field instead of recieving it as a paramenter.

```
public class ExampleAction extends ActionSupport {
  private Integer id;

  public String method() {
    doSomething(this.id);
    return SUCCESS;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) ...
  public String getId() ...
}
```